# How to implement keywords associated function in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uiviewanimation

[image]

For example, when I input several letters, the corresponding words will show up automatically and then I can select them. But how to implement this kind of function? Which kind of UI element should I use ? Should I also input all countries in the world in cord data so that I can get the corresponding results ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image you've shown appears to be simply a UITableView that appears and is populated in response to what the user types in a UITextField.

Comment: Do you mean the corresponding results which show up automatically are on a UITableView? Before I type anything, where is the UITableView? Hidden?  When I input letters in the UITextField, it shows up ?

Comment: Sure, that would be a possible design.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with a table view similar to your screen shot, you can use a `UISearchController`. Here's a [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/113772/uisearchcontroller-tutorial) about it.